# lmdb(Symas Lightning Memory-Mapped Database) not working on CentOS

Tags: database, lmdb

The lmdb code is obtained from the official git repo.

https://gitorious.org/mdb

It is not working with my project with mdb_env_open returning code 38.

The test code that comes with lmdb is not working either.

The error code is also 38, the error message is "Function not implemented".

The same code compiled on ubuntu is working perfectly.

There are few documentation on lmdb, I can't even find what it means to get the return code 38, and there is no corresponding tag in stackoverflow.

Any experts out there?

======================================================

I figure out that it is because of the NFS, moving the database to a local storage solved this problem. But is there any solution that I can use it in the NFS? The local storage space is too small.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From the front page of the docs: http://www.lmdb.tech/doc/

> Do not use LMDB databases on remote filesystems, even between processes on the same host. This breaks flock() on some OSes, possibly memory map sync, and certainly sync between programs on different hosts.

Comment: Is it safe to use LMDB over NFS if you open the DB readonly and you don't try to acquire a lock?

Comment: The link in this answer is now broken, but the question is still interesting.